# How to set two shortcuts for the same thing?

Tags: 12.10, shortcuts

I'd like to be able to set Chrome OS like shortcuts for brightness and volume (and some others), while keeping the default Fn ones. Is there anyway to achieve that?

Comment: Please add the output of `xmodmap -pke | less` to your question.  Thanks!